# SSRS / SSMS record retrieval very slow compared to replicated Crystal Reports

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, crystal-reports

I have replicated in SSRS a report that was originally in Crystal Reports.

The report has a drilldown which returns 15,000 records.

In SSMS the retrieval takes about 4 minutes.  In Crystal Reports, the report is displayed in about 5 seconds.  The drilldown clicks are instant.

I am trying to figure out how to make the SSMS return faster.  Both Crystal and my SSMS query are against the same view.

The view is a series of UNION ALL to collect the records and was written by the system vendor.

The SSRS report takes about 4 minutes also.  The detail records are hidden until toggled.

I cannot figure out why Crystal Reports is so much faster.  **Does Crystal Reports have a way to optimize retrieval of high row count records?**

Comment: quick guess.you hvn't refresh crystal report DB connection.if this doesn't work then very minutely probe each and every formula,query etc in both report,is there anything fishy.I heard SSRS is much faster than CR

Comment: I think Crystal is faster at rendering.  The original Crystal Report collected all data, and allowed drilldown within the report to see any level of detail.  SSRS I believe has to render for the web as many as 76 pages on one section - and there were on the order of 20 to 50 sections.  I solved this part by setting up a main report, with a summary on-demand SSRS report and a detail limited data set SSRS report.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem - in SSMS, changed the stored procedure to pull a large data set into a temp table, then DELETED records not fitting the criteria.

I then replaced an existing view with the limited temp table.  The view had been joined to a large number of other tables and a couple of the criteria were slowing it down.